# Cant reach WEB site via ISP but can via VPN

Tags: internet, routing

A specific WEB site (www.vocaonline.com) times out via my ISP (Suddenlink)
but not if I use a VPN or ATT Network.

You can see that lw-dc4-dist1-te8-1.rtr.liquidweb.com [50.28.96.7]
is the last to return packets. Not sure what is happening here.

Here is a tracert:

without VPN

```
kjo@Giga ~  
$ tracert vocaonline.com  

Tracing route to vocaonline.com [50.28.99.59]  
over a maximum of 30 hops:  

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  router.blackops [192.168.1.1]  
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.  
  3    20 ms     8 ms     8 ms  173-219-237-153.suddenlink.net [173.219.237.153]  
  4    14 ms    13 ms    12 ms  173-219-237-228.suddenlink.net [173.219.237.228]  
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.  
  6    20 ms    14 ms    13 ms  LIQUID-WEB.bear2.Phoenix1.Level3.net [4.28.83.26]  
  7    31 ms    29 ms    29 ms  lw-dc4-core1-nexus-eth4-3.rtr.liquidweb.com [50.28.96.230]  
  8    30 ms    32 ms    29 ms  lw-dc4-dist1-te8-1.rtr.liquidweb.com [50.28.96.7]  
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.  
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.  
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.  
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.  
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.  

Trace complete.
```

With VPN

```
kjo@Giga ~  
$ tracert vocaonline.com  

Tracing route to vocaonline.com [50.28.99.59]  
over a maximum of 30 hops:  

  1   176 ms   177 ms   176 ms  10.13.0.1  
  2   177 ms   179 ms   190 ms  10.0.3.1  
  3   176 ms   177 ms   177 ms  spcr-11.provedorwebmailmarketing.com.br [81.17.21.61]  
  4   176 ms   177 ms   176 ms  190.211.252.129  
  5   181 ms   179 ms   180 ms  179.43.158.133  
  6   180 ms   181 ms   180 ms  te0-0-1-1.rcr12.b021037-0.zrh01.atlas.cogentco.com [149.14.212.121]  
  7   181 ms   180 ms   181 ms  be2079.ccr21.zrh01.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.0.201]  
  8   195 ms   194 ms   195 ms  be2295.ccr41.par01.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.3.53]  
  9   201 ms   201 ms   201 ms  be12497.ccr41.lon13.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.56.129]  
 10   267 ms   266 ms   266 ms  be2317.ccr41.jfk02.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.30.185]  
 11   273 ms   281 ms   274 ms  be2806.ccr41.dca01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.40.106]  
 12   286 ms   293 ms   285 ms  be2112.ccr41.atl01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.7.158]  
 13   307 ms   307 ms   308 ms  be2687.ccr41.iah01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.28.70]  
 14   323 ms   322 ms   323 ms  be2927.ccr21.elp01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.29.222]  
 15   330 ms   331 ms   332 ms  be2930.ccr22.phx02.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.42.77]  
 16   332 ms   340 ms   342 ms  be2914.rcr21.b023003-0.phx02.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.30.242]  
 17   341 ms   344 ms   333 ms  cogent-phx.liquidweb.com [38.122.88.42]  
 18   332 ms   332 ms   332 ms  lw-dc4-core1-nexus-eth4-2.rtr.liquidweb.com [50.28.96.228]  
 19   332 ms   339 ms   338 ms  lw-dc4-dist1-te8-1.rtr.liquidweb.com [50.28.96.7]  
 20   333 ms   332 ms   332 ms  secure.beyondthenet.com [50.28.99.59]  

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Report to liquidweb.com

Comment: FWIW it's completing for me.  15  1116 ms   518 ms   578 ms  lw-dc4-core1-nexus-eth4-3.rtr.liquidweb.com [50.28.96.230]
 16   454 ms   519 ms   519 ms  lw-dc4-dist2-te8-1.rtr.liquidweb.com [50.28.96.9]
 17   462 ms   517 ms   517 ms  secure.beyondthenet.com [50.28.99.59]

Comment: There may be an intermittent issue between the 2nd to last hop, i.e., the liquidweb system at 96.7 and the website at 99.59. Like DavidPostill, I don't see any issue when I run a tracert to www.vocaonline.com, but, as with his tracert, the 2nd to last hop for me is .96.9 not .96.7 as shown for your tracerts. So there appear to be 2 network devices right before the www.vocaonline.com webserver that can provide a path to that server. As he suggested, if you contact the [LiquidWeb](https://www.liquidweb.com/) hosting company, their support staff are in the best position to investigate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue related to your ISP (or there upstreams routing) - it may be that they have reverse path filtering on a route they shouldn't and packets are going out but not coming back through a different route, or that one of the paths is incorrectly advertised somewhere.   It could also be that there is some kind of firewalling or blocking going on.

Using a VPN forces a different route to the endpoint, bypassing the issue.  This issue should be reported to your ISP.

There are some other conceivable but highly unlikely scenarios (like an MTU issue combined with an ICMP block)